# Alternative Google Analytics IO with Pandas

Tags: pandas, google-analytics

The pandas 0.17.1 version has [depreciated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/whatsnew.html#deprecations) the pandas.io.ga module.

What are the alternatives to using google analytics with pandas now? Is there a credible library which can be used now?

Comment: Are the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html) unclear?

Comment: @EdChum The library has import dependencies that are depreciated and it is very difficult to get the library started

Comment: I suggest you post an issue on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) about this

Comment: @EdChum It is already stated the module is depreciated, which is why I am asking for a reliable alternative

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Google2Pandas module](https://github.com/panalysis/Google2Pandas) was created to get around this specific problem. Nothing fancy, simply does what it says on the box.

### v3:

```
from google2pandas import GoogleAnalyticsQuery

query = {\
    'ids'           : <valid_ids>,
    'metrics'       : 'pageviews',
    'dimensions'    : ['date', 'pagePath', 'browser'],
    'filters'       : ['pagePath=~iPhone', 'and', 'browser=~Firefox'],
    'start_date'    : '8daysAgo',
    'max_results'   : 10}

conn = GoogleAnalyticsQuery(secrets='client_secrets_v3.json',
                            token_file_name='analytics.dat')
df, metadata = conn.execute_query(**query)
```

### v4:

```
from google2pandas import GoogleAnalyticsQueryV4

query = {
    'reportRequests': [{
        'viewId' : <valid_ids>,

        'dateRanges': [{
            'startDate' : '8daysAgo',
            'endDate'   : 'today'}],

        'dimensions' : [
            {'name' : 'ga:date'}, 
            {'name' : 'ga:pagePath'},
            {'name' : 'ga:browser'}],

        'metrics'   : [
            {'expression' : 'ga:pageviews'}],

        'dimensionFilterClauses' : [{
            'operator' : 'AND',
            'filters'  : [
                {'dimensionName' : 'ga:browser',
                 'operator' : 'REGEXP',
                 'expressions' : ['Firefox']},

                {'dimensionName' : 'ga:pagePath',
                 'operator' : 'REGEXP',
                 'expressions' : ['iPhone']}]
        }]
    }]
}


conn = GoogleAnalyticsQueryV4(secrets='client_secrets_v4.json')
df = conn.execute_query(query)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Remote Data Access](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html)

You should replace the imports of the following:

```
from pandas.io import data, wb

     With:

from pandas_datareader import data, wb
```

Functions from pandas.io.data and pandas.io.ga extract data from various Internet sources into a DataFrame. Currently the following sources are supported:

Yahoo! Finance
Google Finance
St.Louis FED (FRED)
Kenneth French’s data library
World Bank
Google Analytics

https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader

was discussions that GA to make into the pandas_datareader but so far is not present(not tested, here is the issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8961 ), so far this issue has been addressed with the "googleanalytics" package.

Example:

```
import googleanalytics as ga
accounts = ga.authenticate()
profile = accounts[0].webproperties[0].profile
pageviews = profile.core.query.metrics('pageviews').range('yesterday').value
print(pageviews)
```

https://github.com/debrouwere/google-analytics

[example for the pandas-datareader](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#google-finance)

working code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 24)
f = web.DataReader("F", 'google', start, end)
f.loc['2017-11-24']
```

[image: result with a day]
[image: Sample of how look the dataframe]

Hope it helps!

Comment: @venkat added supported package and that GA didn't make into pandas_datareader. hope is what you were looking for.

Comment: Ok understood. Thanks.